# Why findAll() working and find($id) not?

Tags: symfony

I am facing one problem when getting data in tabs. When I am using

```
$settingsList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1Setting')->
findAll();
```

all data is showing in all tabs.
Now, when I want to filter by 'id'

```
$settingsList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1Setting')->
find(1);
```

It shows nothing.

When I am looking into profiler the query returns one row.

Comment: `find` does not return a collection but a single entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @zerkms above in comments `find` only returns single entity. So, I have used `findBy` like this:

```
$settingsList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1Setting')->
findBy(array('groupId' => '1'));
```